# Cannot get full resolution in Ubuntu on MacBook Pro Retina running in VirtualBox

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, display-resolution

Cannot get full resolution in Ubuntu on VirtualBox.
My MacBook pro: native resolution: 2880 x 1800, 220 dpi.
Guest additions for Ubuntu already installed, but maximum resolution I get is 2560x1600.
I would like to have it full screen.

[image]

Edit:
I get the full resolution with VBoxSVGA graphics controller, but the screen is flickering non stop and VBox is warning against it.

[image]